# Adjust cell data in CSV file, PHP

Tags: php, csv

I am writing header in CSV by using this

```
 fputcsv($fp, $columns);
```

It writes the header in CSV as follow

```
 AED   AFN  ALL AMD ANG AOA ARS AUD AWG AZN BAM BBD BDT BGN BHD BIF BMD BND BOB BRL BSD BTC BTN BWP BYR BZD CAD CDF CHF CLF CLP CNY COP CRC CUC CUP CVE CZK DJF DKK DOP DZD EEK EGP ERN ETB EUR FJD FKP GBP GEL GGP GHS GIP GMD GNF GTQ GYD HKD HNL HRK HTG HUF IDR ILS IMP INR IQD IRR ISK JEP JMD JOD JPY KES KGS KHR KMF KPW KRW KWD KYD KZT LAK LBP LKR LRD LSL LTL LVL LYD MAD MDL MGA MKD MMK MNT MOP MRO MUR MVR MWK MXN MYR MZN NAD NGN NIO NOK NPR NZD OMR PAB PEN PGK PHP PKR PLN PYG QAR RON RSD RUB RWF SAR SBD SCR SDG SEK SGD SHP SLL SOS SRD STD SVC SYP SZL THB TJS TMT TND TOP TRY TTD TWD TZS UAH UGX USD UYU UZS VEF VND VUV WST XAF XAG XAU XCD XDR XOF XPF YER ZAR ZMK ZMW ZWL
```

above data is in $columns array.
Using above data there is 168 columns.

Now i am using for loop to fetch data

```
 $num_records=count($columns);
 for($z=1;$z<$num_records;$z++){
 $rowData=fetchData($columns[$z] ,$columns[$z],1);
 fputcsv($fp, $rowData);
 }
```

Here is fetchData function

```
function fetchData($from,$to,$amount){
$access_key = 'MYKEY';
$endpoint = 'live';
    // initialize CURL:
    if($from=="GNF"){
    $url='http://apilayer.net/api/'.$endpoint.'?access_key='.$access_key.'&from='.$from.'&to='.$to.'&amount='.$amount.'&source='.$from."";
                $ch = curl_init($url);   
                //echo $url;exit;
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                // get the (still encoded) JSON data:
                $json = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                // Decode JSON response:
                $conversionResult = json_decode($json, true);
                $tmpArray=$conversionResult['quotes'];
                if($from=="")
                $from="USD";
                array_unshift($tmpArray, $from);
            }
            return $tmpArray;
    }
```

For GNF its returning 166 data. means less then header. 
Now my problem is because for GNF array has 166 conversion, And we have 168 columns.
So its not showing as per header in CSV.
Please tell me how i can fix this so it will show data as per header.

Here is the generated CSV. You can see its not showing data correctly.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oo0a6ni4xkebat9/currency.csv?dl=0&s=sl

Comment: What is the question here? What is "$num_records"? The amount of columns or rows? Why do you pass the same value as "$from" and "$to"?

Comment: I edited my question. $num_records=count($columns); 
Sorry but that's my logic requirement to pass same value.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing 2 columns because your FOR loop `for($z=1; $z < $num_records; $z++)` ignores the element [0] and the last element [167]. This should fix:

```
$num_records=count($columns);

for($z=0; $z <= $num_records; $z++){

  $rowData=fetchData($columns[$z] ,$columns[$z],1);
  fputcsv($fp, $rowData);

}
```

Comment: But its giving correct columns for other records. returning 168 records by the api key. And its showing correctly. But GNF api returning 166, Thats why its in wrong order.

Comment: That's why you should always use foreach to iterate data structures.